# How can I choose what to print out from a python dictionary and write it out to another file?

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have a file I read in called 'peaks_ee.xpk' and I have a dictionary in which the atom name is the key and the chemical shift is the value.

This is a sample of my peaks_ee.xpk file:

```
label dataset sw sf
1H 1H_2
NOESY_F1eF2e.nv
4807.69238281 4803.07373047
600.402832031 600.402832031
1H.L 1H.P 1H.W 1H.B 1H.E 1H.J 1H.U 1H_2.L 1H_2.P 1H_2.W 1H_2.B 1H_2.E 1H_2.J 1H_2.U vol int stat comment flag0 flag8 flag9
0 {1.H1'} 5.82020 0.05000 0.10000 ++ {0.0} {} {2.H8} 7.61004 0.05000 0.10000 ++ {0.0} {} 0.0 100.0000 0 {} 0 0 0
1 {2.H8} 7.61004 0.05000 0.10000 ++ {0.0} {} {1.H1'} 5.82020 0.05000 0.10000 ++ {0.0} {} 0.0 100.0000 0 {} 0 0 0
2 {1.H8} 8.13712 0.05000 0.10000 ++ {0.0} {} {1.H1'} 5.82020 0.05000 0.10000 ++ {0.0} {} 0.0 100.0000 0 {} 0 0 0
3 {1.H1'} 5.82020 0.05000 0.10000 ++ {0.0} {} {1.H8} 8.13712 0.05000 0.10000 ++ {0.0} {} 0.0 100.0000 0 {} 0 0 0
4 {2.H8} 7.61004 0.05000 0.10000 ++ {0.0} {} {2.H1'} 5.90291 0.05000 0.10000 ++ {0.0} {} 0.0 100.0000 0 {} 0 0 0
5 {2.H1'} 5.90291 0.05000 0.10000 ++ {0.0} {} {2.H8} 7.61004 0.05000 0.10000 ++ {0.0} {} 0.0 100.0000 0 {} 0 0 0
6 {2.H8} 7.61004 0.05000 0.10000 ++ {0.0} {} {1.H1'} 5.82020 0.05000 0.10000 ++ {0.0} {} 0.0 100.0000 0 {} 0 0 0
7 {2.H8} 7.61004 0.05000 0.10000 ++ {0.0} {} {1.H8} 8.13712 0.05000 0.10000 ++ {0.0} {} 0.0 100.0000 0 {} 0 0 0
8 {1.H1'} 5.82020 0.05000 0.10000 ++ {0.0} {} {2.H8} 7.61004 0.05000 0.10000 ++ {0.0} {} 0.0 100.0000 0 {} 0 0 0
9 {1.H8} 8.13712 0.05000 0.10000 ++ {0.0} {} {2.H8} 7.61004 0.05000 0.10000 ++ {0.0} {} 0.0 100.0000 0 {} 0 0 0
```

This is the python code:

```
import pandas as pd

result = {}
text = 'fe'
filename = 'fe_yellow.xpk'

if text == 'ee':
    df = pd.read_csv('peaks_ee.xpk', sep=" ",skiprows=5)

    shift1= df["1H.P"]
    shift2= df["1H_2.P"]

    if filename == 'ee_pinkH1.xpk':
        mask = ((shift1>5.1) & (shift1<6)) & ((shift2>7) & (shift2<8.25))
    elif filename == 'ee_pinkH2.xpk':
    mask = ((shift1>3.25)&(shift1<5))&((shift2>7)&(shift2<8.5))

    result = df[mask]
    result = result[["1H.L","1H_2.L"]]

    tclust_atom = open("tclust.txt","a")

    tclust_atom.write(str(result))
```

The output is:

```
         1H.L    1H_2.L
25    {5.H2'}   {5.H1'}
26    {5.H2'}   {5.H1'}
27    {5.H2'}    {6.H5}
42    {7.H2'}   {7.H1'}
43    {7.H2'}   {7.H1'}
44    {7.H2'}    {8.H5}
60    {9.H2'}   {9.H1'}
61    {9.H2'}   {9.H1'}
62    {9.H2'}   {10.H5}
87   {12.H2'}  {12.H1'}
88   {12.H2'}  {12.H1'}
89   {12.H2'}   {13.H5}
132  {18.H2'}  {18.H1'}
133  {18.H2'}  {18.H1'}
146  {20.H2'}  {20.H1'}
147  {20.H2'}  {20.H1'}
154  {21.H2'}  {21.H1'}
155  {21.H2'}  {21.H1'}
169  {23.H2'}  {23.H1'}
170  {23.H2'}  {23.H1'}
171  {23.H2'}   {24.H5}
```

Instead, I want the output to look like:

`Atom 1  5.H2'   5.H1'
Atom 2  5.H2'   5.H1'
Atom 3  5.H2'   6.H5
Atom 4  7.H2'   7.H1'
Atom 5  7.H2'   7.H1'
Atom 6  7.H2'   8.H5
Atom 7  9.H2'   9.H1'
Atom 8  9.H2'   9.H1'
Atom 9  9.H2'  10.H5
Atom 10 12.H2'  12.H1'
Atom 11 12.H2'  12.H1'
Atom 12 12.H2'  13.H5
Atom 13 18.H2'  18.H1'
Atom 14 18.H2'  18.H1'
Atom 15 20.H2'  20.H1'
Atom 16 20.H2'  20.H1'
Atom 17 21.H2'  21.H1'
Atom 18 21.H2'  21.H1'
Atom 19 23.H2'  23.H1'
Atom 20 23.H2'  23.H1'
Atom 21 23.H2'  24.H5`

So I want to get rid of the first line and get rid of the curly braces in the file I currently have, and I want to add the word "Atom" next to each line along with the number (starting from 1 going to n)

And for example, atom 1 and atom 2 are the same, how can I only print it once instead of twice?

Comment: I think you can do all of that with `pandas` take a look at that library

Comment: Alright, I will look at it, thanks.

Comment: Can I use pandas for this even though the file I am reading in is different from the file I am writing out to and the file i am writing out to is what I want to change @mtkilic

Comment: I tried using df.drop_duplicates() to get rid of repeating values but it didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if this helps you. Replace the last two lines in your code with this code:

```
for col in result.columns:
    result[col] = result[col].str.strip('{} ')
result.drop_duplicates(keep='first', inplace=True)
result = result.set_index([['Atom '+str(i) for i in range(1,len(result)+1)]])
tclust_atom = open("tclust.txt", "a")
result.to_string(tclust_atom, header=False)
```

The `for` loop strips the extra spaces and curly braces from all the series in your DF. `drop_duplicates`, as the name suggests, drops duplicate rows from the DF. And finally `set_index` replaces the integer index with the index where each entry is of the form 'Atom #'.

Comment: Thank you! This worked, just one question, I still have my first line as 
         1H.L    1H_2.L
How can I get rid of this?

Comment: Ohh, My bad. I have updated the code above. You just need to add the key-word argument `header=False`, to the `to_string` method.

Comment: Thank you! And what if I only wanted to choose certain columns to loop over in your for loop? For example, what if my result was 
`result = result[["1H.L","1H.P","1H_2.L","1H_2.P"]]` 
but I wanted to just loop over the columns "1H.L" and "1H_2.L", how do I do that in the for loop, would it be 
`for col["1H.L"] in result.columns:` ?

Comment: Welcome and glad to hear that you got it on your own!